# RenderFlex overflowed when using showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter

I have a `showModalBottomSheet` with textfields in it and `isScrollControlled: true` so it's full screen. when the keyboard pops up, I get an error of

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 18 pixels on the bottom.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (ctx) => SomeCoolSection(),
);
```

I tried adding a `singleChildScrollView`, but it then makes the modal not full screen.

Comment: Kindly provide more code, where `showModalBottomSheet` is wrapped, what is it in `SomeCoolSection`